# Python list clear() strange behaviour

Tags: python, list

```
numbers = [12,23,34]
sum = []
for number in numbers:
    num = []
    for n in str(number):
        num.append(int(n))
    sum.append(num)
print(sum)
```

If i add `num.clear()` AFTER `sum.append(num)`, it's appending empty array to sum. Why is it happening? It looks like `num` isn't appended to `sum` until `num` is cleared

I know that clear() is unnecessary here because i'm reinitializating `num` at the beginning of the loop, but this behaviour is strange for me especially if python interpreter goes line by line

Comment: It is not strange behaviour. when you call clear() on the list, it removes all the elements from that list. So when you come out of the loop, the `num` list is empty. Thus appending an empty list.

Comment: It appends a non-empty list, _which you then explicitly empty_.

Comment: FYI you shouldn't call something `sum`, since that's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: The list that you are referring to as `num`, and the list that was appended to `sum`, are *the same object*.  Any changes made via one name are equally visible by the other name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num = []` and `num.clear()` do two different things.

`num.clear()` tells the list pointed to by `num` to empty itself.
`num = []` reassigns `num` to point to an entirely new (empty) list.

When you do `sum.append(num)`, you're appending that `num` list to `sum` -- `num` still points to that same list, so when you `clear` it, you're clearing that same list that is now part of `sum`.

`num` was not empty at the time you appended it to `sum`, but calling `clear()` subsequently empties it.  Everything is happening in order; your confusion stems from the fact that you believed it's not possible for the list inside `sum` to change after it's been appended.  Surprise, lists are mutable!  :)

(Incidentally, do not name a variable `sum` -- it's the name of a very useful builtin function and if you want to use that function later in your program you'll be confused as to why it's a list instead of a function!)

Answer (score 0):

`num` references a particular mutable object. Even after the object is assigned to the `sum` (btw, don't use `sum` as variable name, it is a python builtin), you clear the exact same object.

Here is another example to show you the mutation of the list:

```
numbers = [12,23,34]
Sum = []
for number in numbers:
    num = []
    for n in str(number):
        num.append(int(n))
    Sum.append(num)
num[0] = 'a'

print(Sum)
# [[1, 2], [2, 3], ['a', 4]]
```

As you can see, `num` still points to the last added sublist and we change its first item